# Wireshark packet dissection codes?

Tags: wireshark, packet

Hi all we have a system which could capture packets accordingly. The only problem now we need some codes on how to interpret the packet just like how wireshark does it so well. Anyplace we can get hold of how wireshark does it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Anyplace we can get hold of how wireshark does it?

[Here](http://anonsvn.wireshark.org/viewvc/).  Start with some of the README files in the `doc` directory, such as `README.design` (doesn't say much, but gives a quick overall view of Wireshark) and `README.dissector` (discusses how dissectors are written).

Bear in mind that [Wireshark has been developed over the course of fifteen years](https://blog.wireshark.org/2013/07/fifteen-years/) and "CONTAINS OVER TWO MILLION LINES OF SOURCE CODE", to quote the `README.packaging` file.  If you want to be able to do *all* that Wireshark does, that's going to take a lot of work.

Comment: @http://anonsvn.wireshark.org/viewvc/ I dont see any document readme just a list of folders. I agree wireshark is very extensive. What I am looking into now is just basic dissector like tcp,udp, arp,icmp. I am also looking if there is any url in the tcp or udp packets. So for this basic functionality where should I start from? How about tshark is it similar to wireshark.

Comment: "I dont see any document readme just a list of folders" Look in the `doc` folder.  "How about tshark is it similar to wireshark?"  Yes, it's built from most of the same code; many of those "OVER TWO MILLION LINES OF SOURCE CODE" are shared between Wireshark and TShark.

Comment: @Ok I found the latest release. I have Readme.design is very short. There is no readme.dissector but its design readme.developer talks about new dissector right. So going back to my case where I just need for tcp,udp,arp,icmp so where to start from ?